# PHP array values returned by request_array all have same index

Tags: php, arrays

```
$item_list = request_array($item);
print_r($item_list);
```

This prints out:

> Array ( [7] => dmulder ) Array ( [7] => blah ) Array ( [7] => wef )
>   Array ( [7] => ) Array ( [7] => ) Array ( [7] => ) Array ( [7] => )
>   Array ( [7] => )

All of the values are indexed 7. Anyone know what causes this?

This is request_array:

```
function request_array($varname) {
    if (!empty($_REQUEST[$varname])) {
        return (array) $_REQUEST[$varname];
    } else {
        return array();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not a standard PHP function. What's its code look like?

Comment: Which function? request_array?

Comment: Didn't realize that. Someone on my team must have written it. Let me find it.

Comment: In addition, you're getting back an array of arrays.... it is impossible to have an array with several elements having the same key.

Comment: Why would you ever need to do what that function does?

Comment: I added the request_array function. I assumed it was just a standard function I'd never heard of before :)

Comment: Now if that isn't the stupidest bit of code... Should be on TDWTF. $_REQUEST is a superglobal and is ALWAYS present, even if just as an empty array.

Comment: Again, I didn't write that function. Don't know who the heck did, but it's probably the cause of some of my problems...

Comment: @David, Do yourself a favor and don't use that function.  It is useless to you.

Comment: I can see that now. This is a pretty large project and I was just following the skeleton someone else setup. I won't use that crap code anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It may solve ur problem....

```
function request_array($varname) {
    if (!empty($_REQUEST[$varname])) {
        return $_REQUEST[$varname];
    } else {
       return array();
    }
}
```

The type-custing is not necessary here...